# Save a relative view and imageviews as a png

Tags: android, imageview

I was just wondering if there is an easy way to save an entire relative view including imageviews as a png or some other image format so the user can save and share it?
Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a screenshot of your view programmatically. Checkout: [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

Comment: you should flag the duplicate posts to maintain the guidelines of the SO.

Comment: @DevendraSingh thanks!